# Looping Through An Array and Moving Array Items To New Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've built an array that looks like this:

```
[
 ["featured", [7]]
 ["news", [8,9]]
]
```

What I need to do is a loop through the parent array and move items in the children arrays to new arrays. So in the above example, I would want to move the values into two new arrays that would look like this:

```
var name = ["featured","news"]
var ids = [[7], [8,9]]
```

I'm not sure the best way to complete this task by looping over the parent array?

Comment: Share your attempt and what was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is inefficient to run 2 loops where a single loop can deliver the solution. Use `.forEach` to loop over each element in the array.

```js
let arr = [
  ["featured", [7]],
  ["news", [8,9]]
];
    
let names = [];
let val = [];
arr.forEach((i) => {
  names.push(i[0]);
  val.push(i[1])
});
    
console.log(names, val); // Will logs ["featured","news"] [[7], [8,9]]
```

Comment: You said _"Will logs `["featured","news"] [7, [8,9]]`"_ but it will log `["featured","news"] [[7], [8,9]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `reduce()` and `forEach()`

```js
let arr = [
 ["featured", [7]],
 ["news", [8,9]]
]

let [names,ids] = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  return ac.forEach((x,i) => x.push(a[i].length === 1 ? a[i][0] : a[i])) || ac;
},[[],[]])
console.log(ids)
console.log(names)
```

You can also use `map()`.

```js
let arr = [
 ["featured", [7]],
 ["news", [8,9]]
]

let ids = arr.map(x => x[1]);
let names = arr.map(x => x[0]);
console.log(ids)
console.log(names)
```

Comment: Why you want to run  2 loops?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik You are right using two loops is bad. I added another way using `reduce()` using single loop

Answer (score 0):

We can also use [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array and test for the elements.

- The first test is for arrays.
- Second test is for strings.

```js
const arr = [
 ["featured", [7]],
 ["news", [8,9]]
];
const ids = arr.flat().filter((itm) => Array.isArray(itm));
const name = arr.flat().filter(itm => typeof itm === "string");
console.log(ids);
console.log(name);
```